# Join not working

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap, join

I am trying to append elements to a list in Mathematica using the join function but it is not working. Here is a small working example:

```
TestList = {};
For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
 Join[TestList, {j}]
 ]
TestList
```

The output is {}, where I want it to be {{1},{2},{3}}

Thank you

Comment: Use `AppendTo` instead of `Join` or use the more awkward `TestList = Join[TestList, {{j}}]`.

Comment: ^ and failing that, use `Reap`/`Sow` instead of `AppendTo` if you can, as `AppendTo` is slower.

Comment: `TestList = {};
First@Last@Reap[For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, Sow[{j}]]]`

Comment: Also you could very easily get this result by doing `List /@ Range[3]` or even `Array[List, 3]`

Comment: @flinty In other words, it'd be a world of pain to work in Mathematica by using `For` loops. Functional paradigm, instead of imperative is the way to go in this case, like almost always (pattern matching filling almost all the rest).

Comment: Perhaps worth explaining that `Join[testList, newElement]` returns the result of joining the `newElement` with `testList` but it does not change `testList`.

Comment: A good pedagogical answer would be useful for beginners who are trying to migrate from an imperative to a functional paradigm. If it already exists, can someone please include a link to it?

Comment: As already said, the better way is using "AppendTo". However,  your code works if you make following change: `For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, TestList = Join[TestList, {j}]]`

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to achieve your desired functionality in Mathematica is

```
testList=Table[{i}, {i, 3}]
```

@flinty and @Syed give a few more very short implementations.

Notice, that while `For` and `Do` functions exist in Mathematica, they are not preferred syntactic constructions. Rather, they were added for compatibility with imperative programming.
In imperative programming languages one may have a function that modifies its arguments but returns no result. This is not the case in functional programming. `Join` returns its result. Therefore your code does not work. `ApplyTo` and `PrependTo` are just a few exceptions to this rule.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to use `Join`, you *could* use [ApplyTo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) (with in-place modification), as in the following example.

But, as has been pointed out in the comments, there are much better ways of achieving the result with *Mathematica*.

```
testList = {};
For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
    testList//=Join[#,{{j}}]&
   ]
testList

(* {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of different Graphics specifications, it usually seems simpler to me to use AppendTo and then return the finished list.

Don't know why, but I can't get this to work as easily with Join. In that case, I have to put the variable for the list of graphics specifications outside of the function, such as a global variable.

```
gList[p_] :=
  Module[
  {
  l = Length[p],
  g = {PointSize[Large]}
  },
  For[
  i = 1, i < l, i++,
  AppendTo[g, #] & /@ {Hue[0.8 i/l], Point[p[[i]]], Circle[p[[i]], 
    0.2 + 0.02 i]}
  ];
 Return[g]
]
```

[image]